# Debian 6 Server Enabling Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop, debian-squeeze, graphical-user-interface

I am currently running a web server on Debian 6 without a GUI. I connect to the server through SSH using putty from my Windows desktop. When managing Windows systems we use RDP to connect remotely, so how would I do the same for my Debian server?

**Note:**

1. I am not an linux power user.
2. My Debian 6 server is a web server serving ruby on rails+mysql, so I would prefer a light weight remote desktop solution.

Comment: If you are going to run Linux you are going to need to learn the CLI.  Even if you connect via X11 or RDP you will find that to administer your server you need to drop down to the CLI to do anything useful.  Linux servers do not have GUIs normally, at best you might setup some kind of web-based interface like webmin, but even that is somewhat hobbled.

Answer (score 3):

You just don't. Remote desktop is the way to do it in windows. The same for Linux is ssh (with putty from windows).

Some of us use the tool called 'screen' which let us to persist sessions instead starting a new one every time we login.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the CLI is the way forward with Linux but if you want remote (X) desktop access, you can install xvncserver.